# Debugging C/C++ project in VScode

Tags: vscode-debugger, symbolicc++

I can't debugging my project. Especially, I can't find class "PassiveElement.cpp". I don't know, what is wrong. How can I fix it?

launch.json

> {
> "version": "0.2.0",
> "configurations": [
> {
> "name": "C/C++: g++ build and debug active file",
> "type": "cppdbg",
> "request": "launch",
> "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main", //dont write suffix
> "args": [],
> "stopAtEntry": false,
> "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
> "environment": [],
> "externalConsole": false,
> "MIMode": "gdb",
> "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
> "preLaunchTask": "Open include and source folders"
> }
> ],
> "tasks": [
> {
> "label": "Open include and source folders",
> "type": "shell",
> "command": "code -r ${workspaceFolder}/include ${workspaceFolder}/source",
> "group": "build"
> }
> ]
> }

c_cpp_properties.json

> {
> "configurations": [
> {
> "name": "Linux",
> "includePath": [
> "${workspaceFolder}/**",
> "${workspaceFolder}/source",
> "${workspaceFolder}/include"
> ],
> "defines": [],
> "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
> "cStandard": "c17",
> "cppStandard": "c++20",
> "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
> "configurationProvider": "BartmanAbyss.amiga-debug",
> "forcedInclude": [],
> "browse": {
> "path": [
> "${workspaceFolder}/include",
> "${workspaceFolder}/source"
> ],
> "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
> }
> }
> ],
> "version": 4
> }

main.cpp

> #include
>
> int main() {
>
> std::cout << "SPICE_NOVAK_TEST_VERSION - ZKOUSKA" << std::endl;
>
> PassiveElement paselem;
>
> while (true){}//infinity cycle
>
> return 0;
> }

Structure project:

SPICE_NOVAK_PROJECT_FOLDER

- vs.code
- c_pp_properties.json
- Launch.json
- include
- PassiveElement.h
- source
- PassiveElement.cpp
- main
- main.cpp

I tried different debugers, configuration, fix launch.json etc.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) and also [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.